# Looping and adding chars to string in LUA

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

It's about Lua/Roblox. (Disclaimer: must be roblox compatible.) I have an array called "array1", and a number value "num" which is 0.

```
local array1 = {"1","2","3","etc."}
local num = 0
```

I do:

```
while 1 do
  wait(1) -- just a little delay between loops
  num = num + 1 -- every loop I'm increasing that "num" value with 1.
  script.Parent.TextLabel.Text = array1[num] -- I'm setting Text to [num]th (in this case 1) of array1. (I get 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc. word every second)
end
```

And it works. Kinda. My problem is, it's setting it to:
"1" and then only "2", not "1" and then "12".

Here's some video of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAsig.jpg

And I don't want it that way. I want to it to be:

> 1, 12, 123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
script.Parent.TextLabel.Text = script.Parent.TextLabel.Text .. array1[num]
```

This will concatenate the previous `Text` value with the next number.